# Cannot fetch data from oracle via spring boot

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, oracle11g

I am very new to spring boot. It seems I can connect to oracle db but cannot fetch data. As a newbie, first I have tried correct credentials and no error was thrown. On the other hand, I changed my password and got invalid password error. So I assume my connection seems to be made?

My full stacktrace can be found here: [spring boot hibernate query invalid user error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441184/spring-boot-hibernate-query-invalid-user-error)

As I saw from some other posts, naming strategy might be a problem since spring converts column names into camel case. Though, in my case it doesn't seems to be a problem since I use

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

which hinders spring to change the column names.

Here is the query that I get:

```
Hibernate: select * from ( select post0_.id as id1_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_1_1_, post0_.author_id as author_id5_0_0_, post0_.body as body2_0_0_, post0_.date as date3_0_0_, post0_.title as title4_0_0_, user1_.fullName as fullName2_1_1_, user1_.passwordHash as passwordHash3_1_1_, user1_.username as username4_1_1_ from posts post0_ left outer join users user1_ on post0_.author_id=user1_.id order by post0_.date DESC ) where rownum <= ?
```

And it the exception thrown:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
```

I have also tried to use native as shown below:

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM POSTS aa JOIN USERS bb ON aa.AUTHOR_ID=bb.ID", nativeQuery = true)
List<Post> findLatest5Posts();}
```

This time no errors were thrown. However, it returns nothing, empty result set.

So how can I remedy this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same kind of error recently. The problem was that I got a column that was called "VALUES", whereas it is a reserved word. I just changed it to "VALUE" and the problem was solved.

I think you might have the same kind of issue with the reserved word "DATE". Try to change it to "CREATION_DATE" for example.

About the second query, you probably don't have the same problem with it because you don't specify the POSTS.DATE column in the select.

Comment: Many thanks @Nis ! I have changed the column name and it worked. In addition, there were some other issues. For ex. when creating POSTS table I had added foreign key manually which was totally unnecessary since I had already given the links through my codes. So I had an error because of that. To sum up, manually adding primary keys to the tables and changing reserved word worked in my case.