# Cannot populate connected tables with automatically generated IDs

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, oracle11g

As a newbie to Spring, I am trying to populate two tables which are connected through a key column. My full stacktrace and created tables can be seen here: [spring boot hibernate query invalid user error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441184/spring-boot-hibernate-query-invalid-user-error)

**In addition here is my form:**

```
package blog.forms;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class NewPostForm {

    @Size(min=2, max=30, message = "Username size should be in the range [2...30]")
    @NotNull
    private String username;
    private String FullName;
    //@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
    //private Date date;
    //private Date date = new Date();
    @NotNull
    private String title;
    @NotNull
    private String post;
    private List<String> references;

    public List<String> getReferences() {
        return references;
    }

    public void setReferences(List<String> references) {
        this.references = references;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return FullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        FullName = fullName;
    }

    /*public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }*/

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getPost() {
        return post;
    }

    public void setPost(String post) {
        this.post = post;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
package blog.controllers;

import blog.LSH.Combinations_Ngrams;
import blog.LSH.Combinations_Ngrams2;
import blog.forms.NewPostForm;
import blog.models.Post;
import blog.models.User;
import blog.services.NotificationService;
import blog.services.PostService;
import blog.services.PostServiceStubImpl;
import blog.services.UserService;
import com.soundcloud.lsh.Main5;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

@Controller
public class CreatePostController {

    @Autowired
    private PostService postService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private NotificationService notifyService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/posts/create")
    public String create(NewPostForm newPostForm) {
        return "posts/create";}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/posts/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createPost(@Valid NewPostForm newPostForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            notifyService.addErrorMessage("Please fill the form correctly!");
            return "posts/create";
        }

        String new_name = newPostForm.getFullName();
        String new_username = newPostForm.getUsername();
        //Date new_date = newPostForm.getDate();
        String new_title = newPostForm.getTitle();
        String new_post = newPostForm.getPost();

        Post new_post_record = new Post(0L, new_title, new_post,new User(10L, new_username, new_name));
        //User new_user_record = new User(10L,new_username, new_name);

        //userService.create(new_user_record);
        postService.create(new_post_record);

        notifyService.addInfoMessage("A new post is created!");
 return "redirect:/";
    }
```

When `postService.create(new_post_record);` is triggered, I got the following logs and error:

```
Hibernate: select post0_.id as id1_0_0_, post0_.author_id as author_id5_0_0_, post0_.body as body2_0_0_, post0_.creation_date as creation_date3_0_0_, post0_.title as title4_0_0_ from posts post0_ where post0_.id=?
Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
Hibernate: insert into posts (author_id, creation_date, title, id, body) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2017-02-25 18:12:07.215  WARN 68332 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1, SQLState: 23000
2017-02-25 18:12:07.215 ERROR 68332 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-00001: unique constraint (MEHMET.POSTS_PK) violated
```

First of all here, why does hibernate change the order of columns? That is, as you see from the link above, the order is like: *id, author_id, title, body, creation_date* in the posts table. However, as seen from the log above, hibernate changes it?

As my second trial, I have changed the @GeneratedValue annotation as below:

**For posts table:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_post",sequenceName="oracle_posts_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq_post")
```

**And for the users table:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_user",sequenceName="oracle_users_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq_user")
```

Besides, I had created the sequences in oracle db as

```
create sequence oracle_users_seq;
create sequence oracle_posts_seq;
```

When running my code relying on the changes, I got:

```
Hibernate: insert into posts (author_id, creation_date, title, id, body) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2017-02-25 18:28:10.086  WARN 69700 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 2291, SQLState: 23000
2017-02-25 18:28:10.087 ERROR 69700 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MEHMET.FK6XVN0811TKYO3NFJK2XVQX6NS) violated - parent key not found

2017-02-25 18:28:10.088  INFO 69700 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2017-02-25 18:28:10.116 ERROR 69700 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [MEHMET.FK6XVN0811TKYO3NFJK2XVQX6NS]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MEHMET.FK6XVN0811TKYO3NFJK2XVQX6NS) violated - parent key not found
```

How can I populate those two tables when a new entry is added?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how relationship is defined between Post and User? making use of Cascade operations you can achieve what you have asked

Comment: @Barath you can see the relation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441184/spring-boot-hibernate-query-invalid-user-error